# Initializing class object inside the other class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class, it names A and A class has 3 another class in its private.

```
class A{
    public:
          A();
          A(int num);
          A(C& mC, P& mP, M& mM, int num);
    //there is a getter and setter for all member this only one example(please check are they right?)
          M getM()const{return pM;} 
          void setM(M classM){ pM = classM ;}
        private:
            C& pC;
            P& pP;
            M& pM;
            int digit= 0;
        };
```

I'm doing that in parameter constucture:

```
A::A(C& mC, P& mP, M& mM, int num):pC(mc),pP(mP),pM(mM)
{
// doing someting here
}
```

But I can't write a code for default and first parameter constructure, when I write something compiler saying to me that :

> error: uninitialized reference member in ‘class A&’ [-fpermissive] 
>   A::A(){

and

> note: ‘A& A::pP’ should be initialized
>        A& pP;

someting like this, several errors and notes.

What should I do? How can I initialize classes in default and first parameter constructure?

Comment: Still I can't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` contains **references** to other object. Unlike pointers, references cannot be null. To make this work, you either need to:

- Use pointers instead of references, and initialize them to `nullptr` is no valid object is provided in the constructor
- Store those members *by value*. This involves a copy of the original arguments, and different in semantics - might not be what you need.